# Ошибка синтаксиса на скобке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

При запуске этого кода:

```
while start_time < end_time:
    text = convert_time_to_string(start_time)
    image = generate_image_with_text(text)
    cv2.imwrite(f'time_images/{text}.jpg', image)
    start_time += timedelta(minutes=1)
```

Появляется ошибка:

```
File "generate_time_images.py", line 26
cv2.imwrite(f'time_images/{text}.jpg', image)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Вероятно, нельзя использовать ф-строку в качестве аргумента функции.

Comment: Какая у вас версия Python? `f-strings` появились в Python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Если версия python ниже 3.6 
используй другой способ форматирования строк

Как вариант
    'time_images/{0}.jpg'.format(text)

Можешь статью глянуть, там описаны старые и новые способы форматирования
[Python 3's f-Strings: An Improved String Formatting Syntax (Guide)](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score 0):

Если очень хочется использовать f-strings в версиях Python < 3.6, есть пакет [`future-fstrings`](https://pypi.org/project/future-fstrings/) с бэкпортом. В шапке модуля нужно добавить магическую строку

```
# -*- coding: future_fstrings -*-
```

или

```
# -*- coding: future-fstrings -*-
```

и готово. Пример: модуль `main.py`:

```
# -*- coding: future_fstrings -*-

if __name__ == '__main__':
    who = 'world'
    s = f'hello {who}'
    print(s)
```

Тест:

```
$ python2.7 main.py
hello world
```

Бонус: вместе с пакетом идет команда `future-fstrings-show`, которая заменяет f-strings на олдовый format в коде:

```
$ future-fstrings-show main.py 
# -*- coding: future_fstrings -*-

if __name__ == '__main__':
    who = 'world'
    s = 'hello {}'.format((who))
    print(s)
```